# Application of Uniform boundedness theorem: $\langle Tx,y\rangle$ bounded for each $x,y$ then $||T||$ is bounded

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

For Hilbert Space $X$, if we have a condition on a subset $F\subset B(X)$ ('set of bounded linear operators on $X$') such that

$$
\{\langle Tx,y\rangle:T\in F\}
$$

is a bounded set for each $x,y\in X$, can I insist as follows?:

Certainly given condition implies (picking $y=Tx$) $\{||Tx||^2:T\in F\}$ is bounded, so for each $x\in X$, $||Tx||$ is bounded, and by uniform boundedness theorem $F$ is a bounded subset of $B(X)$

---

The problem is I think I'm missing something - the sample solution does something more sophiscated than simply stating what I've stated here, but I do not see why I cannot do this. What is wrong with my argument above?

Comment: Heh, old rule of thumb, when looking for the error search in the neighborhood of words like "clearly", "obviously", "certainly"... You can't say "picking $y=Tx$" like that. You're given that the inner product is bounded for each fixed $x$ and $y$, but now $y$ is not fixed, your $y$ depends on $T$.

Comment: Oh god, that's so true - I didn't realize I was implicitly varying $y$ over different choices of $T$. Thanks a lot!